# Python list manipulation - Join lists similar to product

Tags: python

Is there a function that does this magic?

```
[1,2,3] [a, b,c] -> [[a, 1, 2, 3] [b,1,2,3] [c,1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Have you made any effort to write one? And does that second list contain strings? Is the output supposed to be a list of lists (where are the commas)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a tiny modification you can use the `zip` function:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3], y = [4, 5, 6]
print zip(x, [y] * 3)
```

Output:

```
[(1, [4, 5, 6]), (2, [4, 5, 6]), (3, [4, 5, 6])]
```

**Explanation:**
`zip` concatenates each element of the first list with the corresponding element of the second list. Since we want to combine each element of `x` with *all* elements in `y`, we simply put 3 `y`'s into a list and plug this list of lists it into `zip`.

Note that for the more general case of `x` having arbitrary length you should replace `[y] * 3` with `[y] * len(x)`.

Comment: This has the classic Python assignment trick-up. Try `test = list(zip(x, [y]*3))` then `y[1] = 999` and `print(test)`. You'll see that any change to `test` or `y` will change all the others, because they're all referencing the same values.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it's simple to write one.

```
def myfunc(list1, list2):
    return [[i]+list2 for i in list1]

print(myfunc(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]))
# [['a', 1, 2, 3], ['b', 1, 2, 3], ['c', 1, 2, 3]]
```